# Axios PUT call within React MUI Component to Node.js Server does not carry custom-header, while Axios GET call works fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, formik

The following is the React.js MUI component with two Axios calls within it. The `useEffect()` `GET` call works absolutely fine. However, the `PUT` call in the `onSubmit()` function is not working.

```
import {
  Stack,
  Button,
  Typography,
  Box,
  TextField,
  Switch,
} from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// User Profile Schema Validation
const userProfileValidationSchema = yup.object({
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  lastName: yup.string().required(),
  gender: yup.string().max(1).required(),
  dateOfBirth: yup.date().required(),
  phoneNumber: yup
    .number()
    .required("Required")
    .positive()
    .integer()
    .min(1000000000)
    .max(9999999999),
  email: yup
    .string("Enter email ID")
    .required("Email is required")
    .email("Enter a valid email"),
  bamsCollege: yup.string().required(),
  joiningYear: yup.number().required().positive().integer().min(1900).max(2050),
  createdAt: yup.date().required(),
  isBlocked: yup.bool().required(),
});

// Component Function
export default function UserDetailsForm() {
  // TODO: FIXME: THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!!
  // Preparing params and configs for axios calls
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  let { student_id } = useParams();
  let url = "http://localhost:3000/admin/users/" + student_id;
  let editUrl = url + "/edit";
  let getOptions = {
    headers: {
      username: "someone@example.com",
    },
  };
  let putOptions = {
    headers: {
      username: "someone@example.com",
    },
    data: {},
  };

  // State Management
  let [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  // Fetch User Details Function for useEffect() Hook
  async function fetchUserDetails() {
    const response = await axios.get(editUrl, getOptions);
    setUser(await response.data);
  }

  // Fetch details on Load
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserDetails();
  }, []);

  // Formik Object & SUBMIT Function
  const formikUser = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      gender: user.gender,
      dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth,
      phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
      email: user.email,
      bamsCollege: user.bamsCollege,
      joiningYear: user.joiningYear,
      createdAt: user.createdAt,
      isBlocked: user.isBlocked,
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: userProfileValidationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      async function updateUserDetails() {
        putOptions.data = values;
        await axios
          .put(editUrl, putOptions)
          .then(function () {
            navigate(url);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response.status === 404) {
              alert("This Email is not registered on this application!");
            } else {
              alert("ERROR: " + error.message);
            }
          });
      }
      updateUserDetails();
    },
  });

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
      }}
    >
      <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ m: 1 }} gutterBottom>
        Edit User Profile
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="red" sx={{ m: 1 }} gutterBottom>
        DO NOT edit user details, unless absolutely necessary!
      </Typography>
      <form onSubmit={formikUser.handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          label="First Name"
          value={formikUser.values.firstName}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="lastName"
          name="lastName"
          label="Last Name"
          value={formikUser.values.lastName}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="gender"
          name="gender"
          label="Gender"
          value={formikUser.values.gender}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />

        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="dateOfBirth"
          name="dateOfBirth"
          label="Date Of Birth"
          value={formikUser.values.dateOfBirth}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          required
          margin="normal"
          id="phoneNumber"
          name="phoneNumber"
          label="Phone Number"
          value={formikUser.values.phoneNumber}
          onChange={formikUser.handleChange}
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          error={
            formikUser.touched.phoneNumber &&
            Boolean(formikUser.errors.phoneNumber)
          }
          helperText={
            formikUser.touched.phoneNumber && formikUser.errors.phoneNumber
          }
        />

        <TextField
          required
          margin="normal"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          value={formikUser.values.email}
          onChange={formikUser.handleChange}
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          error={formikUser.touched.email && Boolean(formikUser.errors.email)}
          helperText={formikUser.touched.email && formikUser.errors.email}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="bamsCollege"
          name="bamsCollege"
          label="College"
          value={formikUser.values.bamsCollege}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />

        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="joiningYear"
          name="joiningYear"
          label="Joining Year"
          value={formikUser.values.joiningYear}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          id="createdAt"
          name="createdAt"
          label="Member Since"
          value={formikUser.values.createdAt}
          disabled
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        />
        <br />
        <Typography variant="button" color="error" sx={{ m: 1 }} gutterBottom>
          USER IS BLOCKED
        </Typography>
        <Switch
          color="error"
          id="isBlocked"
          name="isBlocked"
          label="Member Status"
          checked={formikUser.values.isBlocked}
          onChange={formikUser.handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Stack marginLeft={1} spacing={2} direction="row">
          <Button color="secondary" variant="outlined" type="submit">
            Update User
          </Button>
          <Button
            color="secondary"
            variant="contained"
            href={"/users/" + user._id}
          >
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The `PUT` request seems to the carrying the right header information (verified by a `console.log()` statement in the browser), however, by the time it reaches the `node.js` backend application, it completely modifies the headers.

Here's the server code on the `node.js` backend application.

```
const express = require('express')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const cors = require('cors')
const router = require('./router')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const log = require('../util/logger')
const { unhandledRequests, errorHandler } = require('../util/errors')

// Test Middleware
const test = require('../middleware/test')

// Configuring Express Server
function createServer() {
  // Associating All Middlware
  const server = express()
  server.use(express.json())
  server.use(helmet())
  server.use(test) // ***Pre CORS request :: For PUT request this is getting executed twice!!! I don't know why.
  server.use(
    cors({
      origin: '*',
      allowedHeaders: '*',
      methods: '*'
    })
  )
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  server.use(fileUpload())
  server.use(log.http)

  // Directing all API requests to the router
  server.use('/', router)

  // Unhandled Requests + Central Error Handling
  server.use(unhandledRequests)
  server.use(errorHandler)

  // Return the server
  return server
}

module.exports = createServer
```

I have checked the header details before the CORS as well as after the CORS middleware in the server file. Although both are slightly different (I don't know why), neither are carrying the custom header of `username`.

Header that is expected. (This is the header from the `GET` request, and shouldn't be that different from the `PUT` request header minus the form data payload.)

```
{
     "host": "localhost:3000",
     "connection": "keep-alive",
     "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"101\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"101\"",
     "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
     "username": "someone@example.com",
     "dnt": "1",
     "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?1",
     "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Mobile Safari/537.36",
     "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Android\"",
     "origin": "http://localhost:5000",
     "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
     "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
     "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
     "referer": "http://localhost:5000/",
     "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
     "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
     "if-none-match": "W/\"179-9vpS3vCBO7UG4qwmDsMBsZ3JOCQ\""
}
```

Headers that are printed before CORS (for some reason, pre CORS middleware is getting executed twice and it prints two different headers.)

```
Pre CORS request details: {
     "host": "localhost:3000",
     "connection": "keep-alive",
     "accept": "*/*",
     "access-control-request-method": "GET",
     "access-control-request-headers": "username",
     "origin": "http://localhost:5000",
     "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Mobile Safari/537.36",
     "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
     "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
     "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
     "referer": "http://localhost:5000/",
     "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
     "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}
Pre CORS request details: {
     "host": "localhost:3000",
     "connection": "keep-alive",
     "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"101\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"101\"",
     "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
     "username": "someone@example.com",
     "dnt": "1",
     "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?1",
     "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Mobile Safari/537.36",
     "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Android\"",
     "origin": "http://localhost:5000",
     "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
     "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
     "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
     "referer": "http://localhost:5000/",
     "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
     "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
     "if-none-match": "W/\"179-9vpS3vCBO7UG4qwmDsMBsZ3JOCQ\""
}
```

Please note that I am completely new to React, MUI and Axios. Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: Please be more specific: What headers do you observe in your backend, and what headers did you expect to observe?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thank you for the quick feedback. I have just updated the expected vs actual headers. As you can see, for some reason for the ```PUT``` request, the middleware is getting executed twice. And each time it prints a slightly different header, and without the custom-header detail of ```username```. I can't figure out if this is a ```cors``` issue, or ```axios``` issue.

Comment: To anyone: If this is not the best way to write this page (GET and PUT Axios calls), I'm happy to hear from you on what could be a better way to handle an EDIT FORM in React.js.

Comment: The first call of the CORS middleware is the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), which the browser makes before a PUT request (but not before a GET request). The second call of the CORS middleware is the PUT request itself.